# How to call update activity on clicking the mobile app's Icon?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am developing my very first mobile application. This one is in cordova and ionic framework. Here for demonstration i have developed login system and one dashboard with some data. My concern is when user logs-in to the application, went to dashboard and suppose he left and came out without doing logout then the next time he clicks on application icon will be redirected to the place where he left but at the same time i want that users data to be updated for that i did following things.
Called function on page body onload:

```
<body onload="onLoad()" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

onLoad function:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);  
}
```

onDeviceReady function:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
if (localStorage.getItem("userid") !== null) {
    $scope.checkForUpdate();
    }
}
```

checkForUpdate function:

```
    $scope.checkForUpdate = function() {
    alert('checking for update');
    }
```

I am just checking whether the alert can be seen or not and i am not getting alert when i am moving out after login and going in it navigates me to place where i left but does not show me alert. Is the device ready event right here or is there different event associated with activity?

Answer (score 0):

The ondeviceready method is only fired once when you start your application. What you really need is to do something on resume:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```